# Почему не работает форма обратной связи?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Вроде по логике всё верно, но не работает. Надеюсь на помощь. Реализовал так:

```js
document.getElementById('feedback-form').addEventListener('submit', function(evt) {
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    f = this;
  evt.preventDefault();
  http.open("POST", "contacts.php", true);
  http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  http.send("name=" + f.name.value + "phone=" + f.phone.value + "&email=" + f.email.value + "&vopr=" + f.vopr.value);
  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
      alert(http.responseText + ', Ваше сообщение получено.\nНаши специалисты ответят Вам в течении 2-х дней.\nБлагодарим за интерес к нашей фирме!');
      f.messageFF.removeAttribute('value'); // очистить поле сообщения (две строки)
      f.messageFF.value = '';
    }
  }
  http.onerror = function() {
    alert('Извините, данные не были переданы');
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<form method="POST" id="feedback-form">
  <div class="box-input">
    <label for="name">Введите имя</label>
    <input required="" type="text" name="name" id="name">
  </div>
  <div class="box-input">
    <label required="" for="email">Введите e-mail</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
  </div>
  <div class="box-input">
    <label for="phone">Введите контактный телефон</label>
    <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone">
  </div>
  <div class="box-input">
    <label for="vopr">Задайте вопрос</label>
    <input type="text" name="vopr" id="vopr">
  </div>
  <div class="box-button">
    <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

И сама отправка на почту:

```
<?
if (array_key_exists('messageFF', $_POST)) {
   $to = 'ravlex@mail.ru';
   $subject = 'Заполнена контактная форма с '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
   $subject = "=?utf-8?b?". base64_encode($subject) ."?=";
   $message = "Имя: ".$_POST['name']."\nEmail: ".$_POST['email']."\nIP: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\nВопрос: ".$_POST['vopr']."\nТелефон: ".$_POST['phone'];
   $headers = 'Content-type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"';
   $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
   $headers .= "Date: ". date('D, d M Y h:i:s O') ."\r\n";
   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
   echo $_POST['name'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Что возвращает var_dump?

Answer (score 1):

В форме ошибок на первый взгляд нет. Но она должна отправить данные на сервер по адресу:

```
http.open("POST", "contacts.php", true);
```

и получить корректный ответ. Вероятнее всего следует протестировать работу сервера, вручную (можно в терминале) оправив ему те-же данные, которые передает форма. Посмотрев ответ вы поймете где проблема.

Answer (score 0):

В строке: 
`http.send("name=" + f.name.value + "phone=" + f.phone.value + "&email=" + f.email.value + "&vopr=" + f.vopr.value);`
`+ "phone=" +` - тоже нужен амперсанд. Иначе, у обработчика все слилось и параметры в POST не те.